# C# WPF - Dynamically Adding Controls In Specific Nested Order

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

Let me start off by saying, I know this is weird. Possibly not the best way to do this, but it's the way it's written and I'm tasked with fixing a bug in it.

**Context**

We have a CRM with dynamic questions that users can create an apply a sort order to. Example being, "Does X customer do X". Then, based on that answer, another question may show up underneath it.

Since dependent questions need to be created dynamically *in order*, I need to order my master list of questions somehow when I begin created these on the client.

The issue is, there could be nested questions that are nested inside of a nest. There's no limit on how many nest levels you can have. So, the way it's written now, is that we grab the highest level question, draw it on the GUI, then for each of those, we grab all the questions dependent on that high-level question. Well, the bug is that if they have nested questions within those nested questions, they get left out.

**Dummy Example Scenario**

QId 1, Sort 1 "Does customer have an address?" *dependent on nothing*

QId 2, Sort 1 "What's the address?" *dependent on QId 1 answer*

QId 3, Sort 2 "Out of state business?" *dependent on QId 1 answer*

QId 4, Sort 1 "What state is this customer in?" *dependent on QId 2 answer*

QId 5, Sort 2 "Do we do business with this customer?" *dependent on nothing*

So I have to somehow order this list in the proper order before I start creating these dynamic controls on the GUI. The existing code that does a foreach won't cut it anymore because of the multi-nested questions.

**What Doesn't Work**

- Ordering by QId
- Ordering by Dependent
- QuestionId Ordering by SortID

I'm stuck here. I know it's complicated. If you need anymore data, let me know.

Comment: If you apply MVVM pattern and have smaller ViewModels (with implicit `DataTemplate`s) in a collection (sorted the way you need) then using something like `ContentControl` bound to `Current` property of the CollectionView you could be able to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to accomplish this. Here is a basic example of that.

```
void Main()
{
    var questions = new List<Question>()
    {
        new Question() { Id = 1 },
        new Question() { Id = 2, ParentId = 1 },
        new Question() { Id = 3, ParentId = 1 },
        new Question() { Id = 4, ParentId = 2 },
        new Question() { Id = 5 }
    };
    var orderedQuestions = new List<Question>();
    AddOrderedChildren(questions, orderedQuestions, null);

    foreach(var question in orderedQuestions)
    {
    question.Id.Dump();
    }
}

public void AddOrderedChildren(List<Question> questions, List<Question> 
orderedQuestions, int? parentId)
{
    foreach(var question in questions.Where(q => q.ParentId == 
    parentId).OrderBy(q=>q.Id))
    {
        orderedQuestions.Add(question);
        AddOrderedChildren(questions, orderedQuestions, question.Id);
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is incredible...Thank you!